# Could not find file error when using Microsoft.VisualBiasic.VBCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

I am creating an in memory .NET DLL which executes function Foo() based dynamic code which had been validated to not have any syntax/runtime errors.  This method works 99% of the time however there are times when the following code throws the following error:

```
Could not find file 'C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\[random string].dll'
```

For example:

```
Could not find file 'C:\Users\mike\AppData\Local\Temp\y2u4taxq.dll'
```

Below is the code that is throwing the error.  I am unable to locate the specific line of code as this only happens in production and I don't get notified of the problem until it is too late.

```
Try
    ' Setup the Compiler Parameters  
    ' Add any referenced assemblies
    With oCParams
        .ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")
        .ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll")
        .ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.dll")

        .CompilerOptions = "/t:library"
        .GenerateInMemory = True
        .IncludeDebugInformation = True
    End With

    ' Compile and get results 
    oCResults = oCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(oCParams, code)

    ' Check for compile time errors 
    If oCResults.Errors.Count <> 0 Then

        Dim CompilerError As CompilerError
        CompilerError = oCResults.Errors(0)
        Throw New Exception(CompilerError.ErrorText)

    Else
        ' No Errors On Compile, so continue to process...

        oAssy = oCResults.CompiledAssembly
        oExecInstance = oAssy.CreateInstance(NamespaceName & "." & ClassName)

        oRetObj = CallByName(oExecInstance, "Foo", CallType.Method, Parameters)
        Return oRetObj

    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    ' RunTime Errors Are Caught Here
    Throw ex

End Try
```

Comment: This is an environmental problem, nothing simple to diagnose.  Maybe anti-malware quarantining the DLL until it finished scanning it.  Maybe the disk is bad.  You could try a retry loop to put a bandaid on it, try it 10 times with a 1 second sleep in between.

Comment: Thanks, Hans.  I was making sure that there was nothing wrong with the code.  I will try your suggestion.